# How can I combine two multi-line output commands?

Tags: bash

I have two commands that each output multiple lines, and I would like to combine them in a way that has a single space in-between each combined line.

These over sized commands are supposed to import an airodump-ng csv file, then extract two columns of data from the file. Then, they cleanup any extra characters I don't need.

> 1. sed -n '/Station/q;p' schoolscan-02.csv | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' | sed -n '1!p' | awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $4}' | tr -d ' '
> 2. sed -n '/Station/q;p' schoolscan-02.csv | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' | sed -n '1!p' | awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $1}'

Command #1 outputs:

> a
>
> b
>
> c
>
> d

And command #2 outputs:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4

I want the output to look like:

> a 1
>
> b 2
>
> c 3
>
> d 4

What command can I use to combine the two of these commands in such a way?

Comment: How are you running the commands? Do you store their output in separate files?

Comment: I apologize, I should've put the commands I used in the original post. I added them now.

Comment: Add schoolscan-02.csv to your question.

Comment: When you don't need to split schoolscan-02.csv in 2 rows of commands, you don't need to put them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `paste` and feed it both streams (one for command):

```
paste -d' ' <(sed -n '/Station/q;p' schoolscan-02.csv | sed '/^[[:space:]]$/d' | sed -n '1!p' | awk -F "\",\"*" '{print $4}' | tr -d ' ') <(sed -n '/Station/q;p' schoolscan-02.csv | sed '/^[[:space:]]$/d' | sed -n '1!p' | awk -F "\",\"*" '{print $1}')
```

Anyways, I can see that tne input to both `awk`s is the same. I'm pretty sure you can accomplish your objectives with a single execution of `awk`.

Comment: This worked, however, I had to recopy my commands again instead of directly copying what you had. Your command didn't quite cut out what I needed to remove properly. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I just copied your commands, no modifications done to them. In short, the advice was `paste -d' ' <(your first command) <(your second command)`

Answer (score 0):

Given that your programs' respective output lies in the files `1` and `2`, you can combine them line-by-line using `paste` like this:

```
paste -d' ' 1 2
```

Comment: or `paste -d' ' <(sed ... | sed ... | sed ... | awk ... | tr ...) <(sed ... | sed ... | sed ... | awk ...)`